# Paypal shipping calculator not overideing

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

I am trying to get Paypal's shipping rate system working i have it set up like so:

- [All State](http://bahnbrenner.com/media/images/ShippingRates.PNG)

  ```
  0.01 - 5 = $5
  5.01 - 10 = $10
  10.01 - 15 = $15
  15.01 - 20 = $20
  ```

and then when I go and place a test order it goes with the default i sent at the start of the trans of $50 shipping. It also looks like its trying to call for the call back and in the sand box it does ask for the call back but does not take it. Item weigh is 8.

Here is a copy of the call to paypal to start the trans:

```
{
    "amt": "339.99",
    "itemAmt": "289.99",
    "maxAmt": "339.99",
    "l_name0": "2.0T TSI TFSI Oil Cooler Kit - Stainless Steel",
    "L_NUMBER0": "226106227",
    "L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0": "8",
    "l_amt0": "289.99",
    "l_qty0": "1",
    "callback": "https://www.bahnbrenner.com/media/php/userman/paypal-callback.php?reason=callback",
    "callbackTimeout": "6",
    "l_shippingOptionIsDefault0": "true",
    "l_shippingOptionName0": "Shipping",
    "l_shippingOptionLabel0": "Ground",
    "l_shippingOptionAmount0": "50.00",
    "shippingAmt": "50.00",
    "RETURNURL": "https://www.bahnbrenner.com/media/php/paypal.php?reason=return",
    "CANCELURL": "https://www.bahnbrenner.com/media/php/cart.php?reason=cancel"
}
```

Is there an option I am missing that tells paypal to deal with the shipping?
What am I missing if i set just the shipping price and nothing else for the shipping it sets it and never resets it once in paypal.
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: So as it turns out I was unable to get this to work so i switched over to cart upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below steps to update one configuration in your PayPal account.

1. Login merchant PayPal account at www.paypal.com
2. Open https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-shipping page directly, then click edit button.
3. Enable " Allow transaction-based shipping settings to override profile settings (Optional)."
4. Click "Save Changes" button.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried with that setting both on and off. Also setting shipping on the call is the only way I have found to have shipping show if i remove it it does not do shipping if I add it that is the only number shown. The `Allow transaction-based shipping settings to override profile settings (Optional).` does not seem to do anything

Comment: marking this as answered because this was the information i would have needed if i had kept going in this way.